# Problem related to communication between two PHP pages

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

Here is my first page where I use a combobox to submit the query:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
//frm.submit();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","infor.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<body bgcolor="white">
<table style="position: absolute; left: 00px; top: 00px;">
<tr><td width="1000" height="400" style="background:#666666">
<table style="position: absolute; left: 40px; top: 40px;">
<tr><td width="900" height="300" style="background:#C8C8C8">
<form name="frm" action="info.php" method="post">




State Name<select name="t1" id="list1" size="1" single onchange="loadXMLDoc();">
<option value="ANDHRA PRADESH">ANDHRA PRADESH</option>
<option value="ASSAM">ASSAM</option>
<option value="BIHAR">BIHAR</option>
<option value="CHATTISGARH">CHATTISGARH</option>
<option value="DELHI">DELHI</option>
<option value="GOA">GOA</option>
<option value="GUJRAT">GUJRAT</option>
<option value="HARYANA">HARYANA</option>
<option value="KERLA">KERLA</option>
<option value="MANIPUR">MANIPUR</option>
<option value="ORISSA">ORISSA</option>
<option value="PANJAB">PANJAB</option>
<option value="TAMILNADU">TAMILNADU</option>
<option value="WEST BANGAL">WEST BANGAL</option>
</select>
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
</form>
<input type="button" value="Close this window" onclick="self.close()">
</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

and here goes my second PHP page where I use `$_POST` to get the variable but it's not working:

```
<?php
print "<br><br>D.Name<select name='t2' size='1' single>";
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("mysql",$conn);
$str="select * from ".$_POST["t1"];
$rs=mysql_query($str);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    print "<option value=ASSAM>".$row['dname']."</option>";
}


mysql_close($conn);
print "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: And the one million $ question is: What's the question?

Comment: "not working" is a vague description.  What is it doing?

Answer (score 1):

Before you do anything, first do the following:

1. Get an established Javascript library (don't bother writing the AJAX calls yourself when there are so many browser specifics to check for that might break your call).  Easy to get something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and just go (use their documentation to put your call into play easily).
2. Have proper [PHP escape / checking / validation](http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/2010/02/16/phpmysql-make-all-post-or-get-variables-safe-for-mysql-insert/), you are currently doing a SQL call with the BARE `POST` variable.  HUGE no-no.

Answer (score 0):

You do this

```
$str="select * from ".$_POST["t1"];
```

Unless you actually have tables corresponding to values like

```
<option value="ANDHRA PRADESH">ANDHRA PRADESH</option>
<option value="ASSAM">ASSAM</option>
<option value="BIHAR">BIHAR</option>
```

You probably wanted to do something like

```
$str = "SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE someColumn = ".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['t1']);
```

Additionally, after

```
$rs=mysql_query($str);
```

Add

```
if(!$rs) {
  trigger_error (mysql_error().'SQL: '.$str);
  exit();
}
```

You will find it easier to debug if you check if what you're doing is working. If you still get nothing returned on form submission (which is what I assume is happening), check your Javascript.

Comment: edited your code to make it more reliable. Hint: a coder is not the only person browsing a site. exit is not very good thing from this point of view

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to understand:

There are **no** 2 php pages.

There are one HTML/JS page and one php page.

It's very important to distinguish HTML/JS code running in the browser from PHP code running on the server.

as for your particular problem, it's very easy.

> xmlhttp.open("GET","infor.php",true);

it clearly says that GET method is used. Why do you expect any data in the $_POST array then? ;)

Comment: still i am not able to fetch data from my database....$_GET["t1] doesn't works....can you tell me why...?

Comment: it seems you're not sending any data from JS

Comment: so how to send if i use submit then the previous page is not displayed....can you tell how i send the valu of t1.

Answer (score 0):

he is not sending any parameters in the GET request as well guys

you need to form the parameters like

var parms = "t1="+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('list1').value)

remember to wrap url encode for this.

on the php page  you should use url_decode($_GET['t1'])

I have answered t in your other post in javascript tag,